# Is it possible to dodge the rubble that sticks out in a square position in Assassin's Creed Revelations' cart race?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I've been repeating this part of the game a lot of times, and there are these little square/rectangular shape of rubble sticking out. I've been attempting to dodge it, but I always hit it. Is there a trick to dodging it or something? Because I stopped playing it a little, so I don't get frustrated. I've also tried going next to the enemy to try and avoid it, but I still hit it slightly. Can anyone perhaps help?

Answer (score 2):

My technique to avoid it is to time the attacks on enemies correctly. If you can hit just before the rubble are at your position, you can usually manage to push the enemy on hit or avoid taking to much damage from the rubble. If you go too soon, you will be bumped out by the other cart and drive straight on the rubble, so be careful.